# A Server need to connect to multi version oracle outside itself via OCI8

Tags: oracle, laravel, oracle11g

I have a server called 192.168.0.1

And i have 2 oracle servers :

- 192.168.0.2 : Oracle version 8
- 192.168.0.3 : Oracle version 11

I have application sometimes connect to Oracle version 8 and sometimes Oracle version 11. And my application connect via Oracle Instant Client.

The problem is if my server inside 192.168.0.1 install Oracle Instant Client version 12, it is not support Oracle version 8 but support for Oracle version 11. But if my server inside 192.168.0.1 install Oracle Instant Client version 10, it is support Oracle Version 8, but not for Oracle version 11.

Unfortunately I must do both connection cause it's not easy if I need to upgrade Oracle version 8 to Oracle version 11 (effected to application that using database Oracle version 8)

> I use Laravel framework via Console->Commands, so i can call database
>   oracle via php artisan  Maybe any trick in Laravel to
>   connect oracle multi version?

Any solutions guys?

Comment: Oh i forget, i use laravel framework with Console->Command. I will add this information so it can fulfill all requirement to post here

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple different connections inside `database.php` file under `connections` array

You can add `$connection` property to your eloquent model:

```
class SomeModel extends Model {
    protected $connection = 'some-connection';
}
```

Or manually set the connection on the model object:

```
$model = new SomeModel();

$model->setConnection('some-connection');
```

Or if using `DB` facade, specify connection:

`DB::connection('some-connection')->(...)`

and in migrations:

`Schema::connection('some-connection')->create(...)`

Source:
http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Comment: I know that. But the problem is on OCI8. OCI8 is bundle of PHP. OCI8 is globally driver for connection to oracle. OCI8 from Oracle Instant Client 12 not support oracle version 8g or 9g but support version 11g. If i can add OCI8 only for my laravel project it will finish my problem but i don't know how to do it.